# Differences in three ways to define a abstract class

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class

I found multiple (slightly different) ways to define abstract classes in Python. I read the documentation and also could not find an answer here on stackoverflow.

The main difference between the three examples (see code below) is:

- `A` sets a new metaclass `abc.ABCMeta` explicitly
- `B` inherits from `abc.ABC`
- `C` inherits from `objects` but defines `@abc.abstractmethod` classes

It seems that `A` and `B` are not different (i.e. also `B` has the new metaclass `abc.ABCMeta`). However, class `C` remains of type `type`.

What are the impacts of not defining a metaclass for `C`? When is it necessary to define the metaclass or is it wrong/bad style to not define the `abc.ABCMeta` metaclass for an abstract class? Nonetheless, the class `C` seems to behave as I expect from an ABC.

```
import abc

class A(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    # Alternatively put __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta here
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class B(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class C(object):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Aimpl(A):

    def foo(self):
        print("Aimpl")


class Bimpl(B):
    def foo(self):
        print("Bimpl")


class Cimpl(C):
    #def foo(self):
     #   print("Cimpl")
     pass

Aimpl().foo()                           # Aimpl
print(isinstance(Aimpl, A))             # False
print(issubclass(Aimpl, A))             # True
print(isinstance(Aimpl, abc.ABCMeta))   # True
print(type(A))                          # <class 'abc.ABCMeta'>
print("---")

Bimpl().foo()                           # Bimpl
print(isinstance(Bimpl, B))             # False
print(issubclass(Bimpl, B))             # True
print(isinstance(Bimpl, abc.ABCMeta))   # True
print(type(B))                          # <class 'abc.ABCMeta'>
print("---")

Cimpl().foo()                           # Cimpl
print(isinstance(Cimpl, C))             # False
print(issubclass(Cimpl, C))             # True
print(isinstance(Cimpl, abc.ABCMeta))   # False
print(type(C))                          # <class 'type'>
print("---")
```

Comment: *"Nonetheless, the class C seems to behave as I expect from an ABC."* – Meaning what exactly? What do you expect and how does it behave?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `abc.ABCMeta` class is necessary to actually enforce the `abstractmethod` behaviour. Its itention is to disallow instantiation of any classes which do not implement the abstract method. The decorator itself cannot enforce that, the metaclass is enforcing the decorator upon instantiation:

```
class Foo:
    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass

Foo()  # works
```

However:

```
class Foo(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass

Foo()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Foo with abstract methods bar
```

So, without the metaclass, the `abstractmethod` decorator doesn't do anything.

`abc.ABC` is merely a shorthand so you can do `Foo(ABC)` instead of `Foo(metaclass=ABCMeta)`, that is all:

> A helper class that has `ABCMeta` as its metaclass. With this class,
>   an abstract base class can be created by simply deriving from `ABC`
>   avoiding sometimes confusing metaclass usage [..]
>
> <sup>https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC</sup>